# How to initialize double dimensional array with zero in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm new to c#. I have two dimensional array. I want to initialize with `0`.

Here is code.
I have an error at `Array.fill()`

```
int N = elements;
int M N * 2;
int[,] amn = new int[M,N];
for(int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    Arrays.fill(amn[i], 0);
```

Answer (score 29):

**You don't need to do anything.**

From [`Arrays (C# Programming Guide)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx)

> The default values of numeric array elements are set to **zero**, and
> reference elements are set to null.

So, when you write;

```
int[,] amn = new int[M,N];
```

all elements initalized to `0`.

You can see on debugger;

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As far as I remember Arrays elements are initialized with `0` or `null` for reference types, so If you make new Array of int's it should have only zeros.

Read this to know more about [Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9b9dty7d.aspx)

> The default values of numeric array elements are set to zero, and reference elements are set to null.

Answer (score 3):

Integer arrays are initialized to 0 by default. So the following code would be functionally equal:

```
int n = elements;
int m = n * 2;
int[,] amn = new int[m, n];
```

Or in short:

```
var amn = new int[elements * 2, elements];
```